# How to change href in HAML if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have 2 different paths that my `workList` holds, and they both path to the same place. I want them to path differently. Here's my code:

```
%table.table-base.table-striped.table-hover{:id => "work-list-table"}
  %tbody
    - @work_list.each do |workList| //there are two items in this object
      %tr{:id => workList.id,href: duplicate_claims_work_lists_path, :style => "cursor:pointer", :onclick=>"workListTrActions(this)"}
      -if workList.work_list_name == "Provider Payments"
           //href = provider_payments_work_lists_path
        %td
          %ul.custom-ul
            %li
              %h4
                =workList.work_list_name
```

As you can see, the two items I have both path to duplicate_claims_work_lists_path. I want to change the href to path to `provider_payments_work_lists_path`. Can I change it in the if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to assign the url to a variable, then use that in the tr element

```
- @work_list.each do |workList| //there are two items in this object
  - url = (workList.work_list_name == "Provider Payments") ? provider_payments_work_lists_path : duplicate_claims_work_lists_path
  %tr{:id => workList.id,href: url, :style => "cursor:pointer", :onclick=>"workListTrActions(this)"}
```